# Show File Directory Under Filename Displayed on VS Code Editor Tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to show the **directory** name of a file under the filename displayed on a VS Code Editor tab? Something like in the image but just using a shorter path (like `/parent1` or `parent1`). The image is taken from a GitHub issue/post.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Podjb.png)

I tried `"workbench.editor.labelFormat": "short"` but got the directory name beside the filename.

EDIT: Link for image - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47142

Comment: "_The image is taken from a GitHub issue/post._" link please :)